# guardar archivos en una carpeta con nombre dado por una variable en r

Tags: r, rstudio

He creado una carpeta mediante **dir.create(as.character(variable1))**, y dependiendo del valor que le de a variable1 me crea una carpeta que lleve su nombre. Mi objetivo es guardar los archivos que vaya creando en esa carpeta.

Los archivos que creo también llevan el nombre de la variable1 (y otra variable que es variable2) pues tengo muchísimos documentos y para ello he usado paste().
Mi modo de guardar los datos es este:

```
write.table(datos, file = paste("C:/Users/Documents/DATOS/datos", variable1, variable2 ,".txt", sep = "_"),
 sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

Lo mas cómodo seria que al hacer el write.table los resultados se guardasen directamente en esa carpeta, pero al llevar el nombre de una variable no se como meter el nombre de la carpeta en el path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta forma te podría ayudar de lo que entiendo en tu pregunta.

```
write.table(datos, 
            file = paste0("C:/Users/Documents/DATOS/datos/", variable1, "/", variable1, "_", variable2 ,".txt"),
            sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

Tambien verifica que antes de crear las carpetas, el directorio este correctamente seteado, es decir en esta ubicación "C:/Users/Documents/DATOS/datos" debe estar el directorio de R, previo a ejecutar `dir.create(as.character(variable1))`